# Identificar se existe uma letra maiúscula na string

Tags: python

Tenho declarada duas determinadas variáveis, no qual uma delas possui letra maiúscula e a outra somente minúsculas. Veja no exemplo abaixo:

```
actor = "Jon Snow"
pet = "wolf"
```

Como posso identificar se existe **pelo menos uma** letra maiúscula na *string*?

Comment: Não sei quais serão as suas entradas, mas pode tentar algo com o `.istitle`. Retornaria true se todas as iniciais da string forem maiúsculas, eg:. "O Despertar Da Força" e false para "O despertar da força" ou "o despertar da força".

Comment: @Vinicius mas precisaria de identificar em qualquer posição. Por exemplo, caso fosse uma senha, verificar se possui pelo menos uma letra maiúscula.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Talvez comparando a string convertida pra minúsculas seria mais fácil.

```
texto = 'não tem maiúsculas'

if texto.lower() == texto:
   print("não tem maiúsculas")
```

Outra forma seria utilizando a função `any` para verificar se algum caractere da string é avaliada como `True` ao chamar o método `isupper`.

Veja:

```
texto = 'meu texto tem caracteres com Maiúsculas'

if any(x.isupper() for x in texto):
     print('Tem maiúscula')
```

Comment: o primeiro jeito é o mais eficiente, o segundo o "mais legal" :-)  num mundo ideal seria o "one and obvious way" - mas infelizmente temos um overhead grande pra chamar funções a partir de código Python paracada caractere.

Comment: @jsbueno é bonito ver  essa expressão com `any`. Eu não sabia pra que tinha `any` em Python, mas imaginei pra que servia. Fiz até uma [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/193622/como-funciona-o-any-e-o-all-em-python) pra ajudar quem não conhece.

Comment: Tem o "any" e o "all"  -  para coisas pequenas, o quando o que é feito na expressão é proporcionalmente mais complicado do que nesse caso, é muito prático. Mas para um texto de algumas dezenas de KB, por exemplo, a diferença entre os seus dois métodos é significativa.

Comment: @jsbueno nesse caso, se o uso do `any` é pesado, com regex seria pior ainda, certo?

Comment: Não  - por que a regex usa um engine otimizado rodando em código nativo. O `any` fica pesado aí por que faz uma function call em Python para cada caractére, enquanto que o `upper`  vai transformar direto todos os caractéres numa única função em código nativo. (vai usar mais memória também -  o `isupper` usaria algumas dezenas de bytes para cada chamada, no máximo, reusadas  - o `upper` sempre vai criar outra string inteira - se forem dezenas de MB de texto faz diferença.

Comment: Agora, a regexp tem que usar  o `\w` , claro - só que ele pega todas as letra,s ma snao distingue maiúsculas e minúsculas: não é trivial resolverisso com regexp.

Comment: @jsbueno obrigado, cara. A primeira coisa que vem na cabeça quando se fala em `regex` é o "peso". Não sabia dessa diferença :p

Answer (score 2):

> Usando regex fica rápido, simples e eficiente:

```
>>>import re

>>> # Retornando a primeira Maiúscula
... print (re.search('[A-Z]', 'Jon Snow').group())
J

>>> # Retornando todas as maiúsculas
... print (re.findall('[A-Z]','Jon Snow'))
['J', 'S']
```

Se não houver maíuscula no primeiro caso, o retorno seria None, no segundo uma lista vazia.

> Solução para acentução

```
>>> import unicodedata as uncd
>>> print (re.findall('[A-Z]',uncd.normalize('NFKD','Jon Snow É o Á')) )
['J', 'S', 'E', 'A']
```

Comment: Funciona bem para quem não usa acentos, mas e com acentos? Não creio que para uma coisa simples Regex será mais rápido ou simples que `.lower()`.

Comment: Editei e coloquei a solução com acentos. Eu não disse que a solução com regex é mais rápida, para isso teriamos que fazer testes, mas na minha opinião é mais simples e mais pythonico, Não é por acaso que o Django elegeu regex para o roteamento de Urls, aliás a documentação destaca que para casos simples, regex é uma das melhores soluções, alguns autores dizem que é imbativel.

Comment: Você disse `rápido` e `eficiente`, ambos levam a entender exatamente isto, o que não é um fato, mas a micro-optimização é minima mesmo, no entanto mudaria o texto, porque não é verdadeiro, talvez queira dizer outra coisa, mas as pessoas vão entender errado a maneira que foi escrita, sobre regex nas URLs do Django, isto é para facilitar o desenvolvimento e não porque X é melhor Y, ele é melhor na condição na necessidade de criar URLs customizadas, não quer dizer que você vai precisar um canhão sempre que quiser matar formigas.

Comment: Talvez seja uma maneira prática de se recuperar as letras maiúsculas, mas com certeza não é a mais pythonica de apenas verificar se existem, como é perguntado no problema. Apenas o `if` utilizando o `lower` já resolve a questão e fica muito mais legível o código.

Comment: Eu disse Rápido, Simples e Eficiente, mas não disse em nenhum momento que é melhor, ou que x é melhor que y. Além disso, procurei deixar claro que se trata da minha opinião. Minha intenção foi somente apresentar mais uma alternativa, que pode atender somente a questao em si que é detectar a presença de maiuscula **(com search)** e ainda um plus **(com findall)** para detectar todas . **No stress.** :-)

Comment: Como eu disse já, o que você escreve pode ser interpretado de maneiras diferentes, é uma dica, orientação, então entenda como tal para você melhorar e não como uma critica.

Answer (score 2):

Uma possibilidade de solução seria iterando pelos caracteres da string e inquirir qual sua [Categoria Geral Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/#GC_Values_Table) via a função da biblioteca padrão [`unicodedata.category()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.category).
No caso a procura é pela categoria `Lu` que significa *Letter Uppercase* ou letras maiúsculas

```
import unicodedata

s = "pÁssaro"

for c in s:
    if unicodedata.category(c) == "Lu":
        print('Existem letras maiúsculas.')
        break
else:
    print('Não há letras maiúsculas.')
```

<sup>Teste o código no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/uppercase#main.py)</sup>

Comment: Vale mencionar que `isupper()` seria equivalente: segundo a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#id15), internamente ele (e os outros métodos, como `islower`) verifica a categoria Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer:

```
p = "Jon Snow"
for x in p:
  c = ord(x)
  if c >= 65 and c <= 90:
    print("Maiscula encontrada")
```

Comment: "Assumindo ASCII" já está errado. Por favor, leia http://local.joelonsoftware.com/wiki/O_M%C3%ADnimo_Absoluto_Que_Todos_os_Programadores_de_Software_Precisam,_Absolutamente,_Positivamente_de_Saber_Sobre_Unicode_e_Conjuntos_de_Caracteres_(Sem_Desculpas!)

Comment: Por que não usando o pacote string se é para pegar somente as maiúsculas de um tal conjunto..

Answer (score 0):

Outra forma interessante de resolver esta questão é implementando uma função do tipo `def`. Neste caso o código ficaria:

```
def maiuscula(p):
    if any(i.isupper() for i in p):
        return True
    return False


palavra = input('Digite uma palavra: ')

print(maiuscula(palavra))
```

Esta função recebe uma palavra e verifica se na mesma existe letras maiúsculas e, se tiver , pelo menos, 1 letra maiúscula a função retorna **True**. Caso contrário, retorna **False**.