# Como funciona o any e o all em Python?

Tags: python, funções

Como funciona as funções `any` e `all` em Python e quais são as diferenças entre elas?

Por acaso elas são funções equivalentes à `Array.prototype.some` e `Array.prototype.every` do Javascript?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Não sei o suficiente dos fundamentos de Javascript - mas superficialmente sim.

O "any" e  "all" em Python são funções que recebem uma sequência ou um iterador e verificam a condição de verdade para cada elemento: assim que o primeiro elemento for verdadeiro, `any` retorna `True` - se não, percorre a sequência até o final e retorna `False`.

`all` faz o contrário - retorna `False` no primeiro elemento com valor falso (em Python, qualquer sequência ou mapping vazio, None, valor numérico 0, ou uma classe que implemente um método `__bool__` customizado que retorne `False`) - e retorna `True` apenas se todos os elementos tem valor verdadeiro.

Podem ser usados diretamente com uma lista, iterável ou dicionário (no caso de dicionários, são avaliadas as chaves), mas o mais usual é que sejam usados com uma *"generator expression"* - isso é, uma expressão com um `for` inline que efetue alguma operação para cada elemento de uma sequência.

`all(chr.isdigit() for chr in "313213882")` por exemplo vai retornar `True`

A expressão que precede o `for` é equivalente ao corpo de uma função de callback, obrigatória em linguagens que não tem a construção sintática dos generator expressions.  Em Python, se uma expressão com operadores começar a ficar complicada, basta fazer uma chamada de função no mesmo ponto (o exemplo dado chama um método). Pode-se definir uma função de callback com lambda ali, mas ela seria redundante - e teria o overhead da função ser recriada para cada elemento da sequência:

`all((lambda chr: chr.isdigit())(chr) for chr in "313213882")`  - forma errada!  :-)

Aproveitando para clarificar a diferença entre "generator expression" e "list comprehension":

São parecidos - "list comprehension" é quando usamos o mesmo tipo expressão entre colchetes (`[`e `]`) - ai o for é executado imediatamente, e o resultado final é uma lista. Também existem os "set comprehension", que usam a  mesma sintaxe  e "dict comprehension"  - quase a mesma sintaxe, mas tem que ter duas expressões separadas por ":" - uma para a chave, outra para o valor do dicionário.

Quando se limita a expressão com parenteses, ou, dependendo do uso, nem se limita ela (por exemplo, numa atribuição de variável) -  o termo correto é "generator expression" - por que o resultado final é um "generator": um objeto que implementa o protocolo de iterável do Python, e que vai gerar um único elemento a cada vez que for iterado - isso é, for chamado seu método interno `__next__`, seja explicitamente, com a função `next`, ou implicitamente, num `for`.

Por exemplo, na chamada ao `any` e `all`, não precisamos de parenteses extras ou colchetes: essas funções recebem um iterável e o consomem (não necessariamente todo ele) - são generators. Usar os colchetes na chamada (e por tanto, uma list comprehension) vai dar o mesmo resultado final, mas o Python vai gerar todos os elementos da lista (e portanto, "resolver" a expressão entre colchetes) e  chamar a função: `all([chr.isdigit() for chr in "313213882"])`. Não faça isso - além de potencialmente rodar a expressção pra elementos desnecessários, você está alocando a memória para tdos os elementos da sequência de uma vez, quando provavelmente só precisaria de um por vez.

Comment: *Generator Expression*? Eu pensei que o nome fosse *List comphreension*

Comment: Aproveitei para clarificar a diferneça enre list-comprehension e generator-expressions.