# Função não funciona em todos os casos de teste

Tags: python, python-3.x, matriz

Preciso fazer uma função pra verificar se uma matriz é quadrada:

```
    def eh_quadrada(matriz):
        '''Função que verifica se uma matriz é quadrada.
        list->bool'''
        if len(matriz)==len(matriz[0]):
            return True

        else:
            return False
```

Esse código só não funciona quando a matriz de entrada é vazia: `[[]]`.

O que eu poderia fazer quando a entrada fosse uma matriz vazia, para esse código funcionar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente, `[[]]` não é vazia: isso é uma lista que possui um elemento (e esse elemento é uma lista vazia).

Então basta verificar essa condição, ou seja, o tamanho da matriz é 1 e o tamanho do primeiro elemento é zero.

Outro detalhe é que não adianta verificar somente a primeira linha da matriz. Pois se eu tiver algo assim:

```
matriz = [
  [1, 2],
  [3]
]
```

Sua função vai retornar `True`, pois você não está verificando da segunda linha em diante. Para ter certeza que a matriz é quadrada você precisa verificar todas as linhas:

```
def eh_quadrada(matriz):
    # caso especial de matriz "vazia"
    if len(matriz) == 1 and len(matriz[0]) == 0:
        return True
    # todas as linhas devem ter o mesmo tamanho da matriz 
    return all(len(matriz) == len(linha) for linha in matriz)
```

[`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) verifica se todos os elementos satisfazem a condição (que no caso, é ter o mesmo tamanho da matriz). Se algum deles tiver tamanho diferente, retorna `False`.

Comment: Meio _off_, mas vou perguntar mesmo. :D O que você passou para `all`? É tipo uma _list comprehension_ implícita? É a primeira vez que vi isso. Sei que `all` espera um _iterable_, aí o Python consegue entender que aquilo é, de fato, um _iterable_?

Comment: @LuizFelipe É uma [*generator expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) - é similar a list comprehension (leia o link, que já explica tudo) :-)

Comment: @LuizFelipe Relacionado ao assunto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/193625/112052