# Como printar na mesma linha em python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

A função `print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)` possui o argumento `end` e por padrão `end='\n'`, eu sei que se trocar para `end=' '` vai printar na mesma linha.

Porém estou avançando meus conhecimentos em Python e pensei numa atividade que preciso 'printar' na mesma linha uma formula matemática lado a lado, exemplo:

```
 1       2       3
+1      +2      +3
--      --      --
```

Possui alguma forma de 'printar' desta formula acima usando um `for` mais ou menos nesse exemplo "1\n+1\n--" ou para conseguir esse efeito preciso criar uma matriz e usar dois for (rows,columns) para 'printar' o resultado que eu quero?

Realizei um código de teste. [Veja aqui](https://replit.com/@Dennisrochaa/printFunction#main.py):

```
my_list=(["1 + 1","2 + 2","3 + 3"])
for i in my_list:
  print(i, end=" | ")

print("\n\n\n")
for j in my_list:
  print(f" {j.split()[0]}\n{j.split()[1]}{j.split()[2]}\n--", end="")

print("\n\n\n")
print("""
------Espectativa-----
 1     2    3
+1    +2   +3
--    --   -- 
""")
```

Quero entender se é possível fazer como o exemplo.

Comment: Para esse caso específico poderia ser algo assim: https://ideone.com/S12uj7 - claro que se as expressões puderem variar de tamanho, ter números com mais de 1 dígito, etc, aí teria que adaptar

Comment: Funcionou como estava esperando. Vou procurar entender o que acontece e em cada parte do código para aprimorar meu conhecimento. Obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O terminal visto pelo Python e outras linguagens sempre é um conjunto de linhas de cima pra baixo - então, se você tem informação que vai ser distribuida em multiplas linhas, em paralelo com informação que deveria ir em outras colunas, sempre vai ter que criar primeiro na memória uma estrutura com todas as informações que você quer,
e em seguida imprimir essa estrutura linha a linha.

Algo do tipo:

```
my_list=(["1 + 1","2 + 2","3 + 3"])

saida = []

for elemento in my_list:
    linhas_por_elemento = elemento.split(" ", 1) # separa os elementos de exemplo - com a parte esperada em cada linha 
    for j, linha_do_elemento in enumerate(linhas_por_elemento):
        if len(saida) <= j:
            # a linha onde essa informação vai entrar ainda não foi criada:
            saida.append([])
        saida[j].append(linha_do_elemento)
# nesse ponto, a variável saída é uma lista de listas - onde cada elemento da mesma é uma lista com as strings que vão em cada coluna

# O print abaixo concatena com "|" os elementos de uma mesma linha, e concatena cada linha de texto com "\n":
    
print("\n".join("|".join(f"{elemento:>8s}" for elemento in linha) for linha in saida))
```

Alternativamente, você pode usar uma biblioteca que te deixe usar o terminal como uma "saida 2D" - eu desenvolvo a lib "terminedia" que permite isso:

```
import terminedia as TM
sc = TM.Screen()

for coluna, elemento in enumerate(my_list):
    for linha, parte in enumerate(elemento.split(" ", 1)):
        sc.print_at((coluna * 8, linha), parte)

sc.update()
```

(é só instalar o terminedia com "pip install terminedia" )
O objeto "sc" permite tratar o terminal como uma matriz 2D -e
o print_at requer como primeiro parâmetro uma tupla
com as coordenadas de linha, coluna onde você quer
fazer a impressão)

Comment: Muito interessante, vi que é possível usar um for dentro do print, eu não sabia que era possível. Pode me indicar algum livro que ensine funções mais complexas? Os cursos que fiz nunca mostra funções mais complexas. Vou pesquisar sobre essa lib que você está desenvolvendo

Comment: O "print" é uma função normalizinha. O que é possível é usar um `for` dentro de uma expressão. (O print recebe como parâmetro o resultado da expressão). No caso aí, a expressão com `for` é passada para o método `join` - o que o `join` retorna é que vai para o print. E aí, por fim, esses `for` dentro de expressões criam as `generator expressions`

Comment: Acho que essa resposta aqui pode explicar bem as generator expressions: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/193622/como-funciona-o-any-e-o-all-em-python/193625#193625